# In scrutinizer PHP7.1 + apache2 environment crashes

Tags: apache, php-7.1, scrutinizer

I have this scrutinizer environment

```
build:
    environment:
        php: '7.1'
        node: '4.2.2'
        selenium:
            version: '2.53'
        hosts:
            domainselenium: '127.0.0.1'
            domainweb.docker: '127.0.0.1'
        apache2:
            modules: ['rewrite', 'ssl', 'macro', 'headers']
            sites:
                domain:
                    web_root: 'web/'
                    host: 'domain.docker'
                    rules:
                        - 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f'
                        - 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_test.php/$1 [QSA,L]'
```

But scrutinizer gives me `Configuring Apache2` error. If i use php '7.0' everything works. For me setup seems ok, but maybe you have any ideas how to make it work on php7.1?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So the solution is to disable accelerator in php ini file. Check php environment section in yaml bellow.

```
build:
    environment:
        php:
            version: '7.1'
            ini:
                'apc.enable_cli': '1'
                'apc.enabled': '0'
        node: '4.2.2'
        selenium:
            version: '2.53'
        hosts:
            domainselenium: '127.0.0.1'
            domainweb.docker: '127.0.0.1'
        apache2:
            modules: ['rewrite', 'ssl', 'macro', 'headers']
            sites:
                domain:
                    web_root: 'web/'
                    host: 'domain.docker'
                    rules:
                        - 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f'
                        - 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_test.php/$1 [QSA,L]'
```